# Вылетает ошибка при создании переменной

Tags: linux, shell

При создании переменной настройки программы вылетает следующая ошибка:

```
olegratnikov@olegratnikov-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/android-ndk-r11c$ STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN=path/to/android-ndk-r11c/sysroot-arm/bin make
make: *** Не заданы цели и не найден make-файл.  Останов.
```

При установки следовал следующим инструкциям:

```
    wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r11c-linux-x86_64.zip
unzip android-ndk-r11c-linux-x86_64.zip
cd android-ndk-r11c
./build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --ndk-dir=`pwd` \
  --arch=arm --platform=android-24 \
  --install-dir=./sysroot-arm/ \
  --verbose
```

Comment: в папке нет файла `makefile`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: а у вас что за ОС?